# How to split using colum data in sql based on delimeter and output same in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2014

I want to split column value in table separated by `,` output each value as separate row

**Actual Data**
User_Prefereces

```
ID  USERID  Preferences
1   X1234   Football,Tennis,Swimming,Hiking
2   X2345   Cricket
3   X3456   Dancing,Reading
4   X4567   Games,Cricket,Tennis
```

**Expected Output**

```
ID  USERID  Preferences
1   X1234   Football
1   X1234   Tennis
1   X1234   Swimming
1   X1234   Hiking
2   X2345   Cricket
3   X3456   Dancing
3   X3456   Reading
4   X4567   Games
4   X4567   Cricket
4   X4567   Tennis
```

I use SQL Server 2014 and trying to use below Split function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_SplitString]
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter NCHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT ,@rn INT =1
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
       
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS, @string COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS, @start)
        SET @rn = @rn+1
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Can i get desired output using above function, i tried to use it as but its not working

```
 SELECT * FN_SplitString(ShowOnPageID,',') AS Col1 FROM Banner
```

UPDATE *** Possible SOlution***

FUNCTION

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitStringsNew
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS APPLY sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
GO
```

**SQL To use same**

```
  SELECT b.ID, f.Item FROM User_PreferecesAS b
  CROSS APPLY SplitStringsNew(b.Preferences, ',') as f;
```

I tried it and its working not sure how good this is in terms or performance

Comment: Honestly SQL Server is not really the right tool for this job.  I would probably export the table as CSV, then reformat as you want in Java or maybe even Notepad++.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Data keeps change and i want desired out only for frontend  feature, I output could be in view or temp table.. Same could be done using C# but then i have call put data in string, split them and then store them in Array or as list.. i was wondering if same could be done using SQL so that frond end logic would be very simple ..

Comment: Such CSV data should ideally not even be stored in your SQL database.  If this requirement is something for production, then don't even think of going this route, even if you get an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy with **STRING_SPLIT()**  and **cross apply**:

```
select id,userid, Pref.Value --SplitData
from tabsplit
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (Preferences, ',') Pref
```

**Output:**

```
|id|userid|Value   |
 -- ------ --------
|1 |X1234 |Football|
|1 |X1234 |Tennis  |
|1 |X1234 |Swimming|
|1 |X1234 |Hiking  |
|2 |X2345 |Cricket |
|3 |X3456 |Dancing |
|3 |X3456 |Reading |
|4 |X4567 |Games   |
|4 |X4567 |Cricket |
|4 |X4567 |Tennis  |
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is builtin function in 2016 version and onwards not in 2014 i belive..

Comment: Oops! sorry. Let me find another way.

Comment: @Learning Don't find another way, upgrade your instance. 2014 is already out of support

Comment: Surely it's the best option if possible.